# Python Regex after a known string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string formatted as such: `| birth_date = 22 January 1898 |`

I want to write a regex that looks for birth_date, and gets a 4 digit sequence of digits after birth_date up until the pipe character

Comment: Have tried anything ?

Comment: Which 4 digits? The year?

Comment: Something like `\d{4}\s*\|$` I think would do it, presuming the string ends at the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.sub(r'\D', '', "| birth_date = 22 January 1898 |")
# output => 221898

# if you want only the last 4 digits:
print re.sub(r'(\D)', '', "| birth_date = 22 January 1898 |")[-4:]
# output => 1898
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the year, and all strings are identically formatted, you can avoid regex:

```
test = '| birth_date = 22 January 1898 |'
year = test.split()[-2]
print year
```

Expanding this into a function:

```
def get_year(input):
    '''Returns year as integer, empty string if invalid input.'''

    output = ''
    if 'birth_date' in input:
        output = input.split()[-2]
        try:
            output = int(output)
        except:
            output = ''
    return output

test = ['| birth_date = 22 January 1898 |',
        '| death_date = 22 January 1898 |',
        '| birth_date = 22 January XXXMLC |',
        '| birth_date = 23 January 1961 |']

for input in test:    
    result = get_year(input)
    if not result:
        result = 'Invalid input'
    print(input, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have written an isint function that checks if the number is an int

```
for x in range(0, len(string) - len(str(int))):
    if isint(string[x:x+len(str(int))]):
        print string[x:x + len(str(int))]
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can be like this:

```
birth_date\s*=\s*\d{1,2}\s*\w+\s*(\d{4})\s*\|
```

And the year is in the group 1.

```
>>> pat = re.compile(r'birth_date\s*=\s*\d{1,2}\s*\w+\s*(\d{4})\s*\|')
>>> print pat.search('| birth_date = 22 January 1898 |').group(1)
1898
```